# FS2: is it possible to complete Queue gracefully?

Tags: scala, fs2

Suppose that I want to convert some legacy asynchronous API into FS2 Streams.
The API provides an interface with 3 callbacks: next element, success, error.
I'd like the Stream to emit all the elements and then complete upon receiving success or error callback.

FS2 guide (https://functional-streams-for-scala.github.io/fs2/guide.html) suggests using `fs2.Queue` for such situations,
and it works great for enqueueing, but all the examples I've seen so far expect that the stream that `queue.dequeue` returns will never complete - 
there's no obvious way to handle success/error callback in my situation.
I've tried to use `queue.dequeue.interruptWhen(...here goes the signal...)`, but if success/error callback arrives before the client has read the data from the stream,
stream gets terminated prematurely - there are still unread elements. I'd like the consumer to finish reading them before completing the stream.

Is it possible to do that with FS2? With Akka Streams it's trivial - `SourceQueueWithComplete` has `complete` and `fail` methods.

UPDATE:
I was able to get good enough result by wrapping elements in Option and considering None as a signal to stop reading the stream, and additionally by using a Promise to propagate errors:

```
queue.dequeue
.interruptWhen(interruptingPromise.get)
.takeWhile(_.isDefined).map(_.get)
```

However, did I overlook more natural way of doing such things?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One idiomatic way to do this is to create a `Queue[Option[A]]` instead of `Queue[A]`. When enqueueing, wrap in `Some`, and you can explicitly enqueue `None` to signal completion. On the dequeueing side, do `q.dequeue.unNoneTerminate`, which gives you a `Stream[F, A]` that terminates once the Queue emits `None`

Answer (score 7):

Answer to your update: Combine `unNoneTerminate` with `rethrow`, which takes a `Stream[F, Either[Throwable, A]]` and returns a `Stream[F, A]` that errors out with `Stream.raiseError` when it encouters a throwable.

Your complete stack would then be a `Stream[F, Either[Throwable, Option[A]]]` and you unwrap into `Stream[F,A]` by calling `.rethrow.unNoneTerminate`